# Не будем обманывать пользователей фразой "Этот вопрос уже был задан и имеет решение..."

Tags: предложение, локализация

Предлагаю переформулировать причину закрытия "Этот вопрос уже был задан и имеет решение..." на "Этот вопрос уже был задан и возможно имеет решение", так как не всегда решение может там присутствовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а ещё как вариант заменить слово "этот" на слово "похожий", всё же вопрос там не _точно_ такой же

Comment: Ну нет смысла закрывать вопрос лишь потому, что он похож на другой какой-то. Я к тому, если другой похожий вопрос был задан и не имеет решения, то и смысла закрывать текущий - нет. Ибо редиректить человека в космос - непонятно зачем))

Answer (score 4):

В формулировке важны обе части: вопрос уже задан и у него уже есть решение. Система не даёт выбрать вопрос, в котором нет ответа, помеченного как решение. Поэтому если на сайте повторяют вопрос, на который до сих пор нет удовлетворительного ответа, то его нельзя закрыть как дубликат. Миссия не закончена ;)

Поэтому причина закрытия сама по себе соответствует реальности, но возникают другие проблемы:

1. такой вопрос уже есть и хороший ответ в нём есть, но ответ не отметили как решение и отметку о дубликате сделать не получится;
2. как решение отмечен неудачный ответ, и отправлять туда людей неохота;
3. заданный вопрос похож на существующий, но его можно решить по другому, поэтому закрывать его не надо.

Из-за этого приходится трижды перепроверить и семь раз подумать, действительно ли это дубликат и есть ли на него ответ.

Comment: Не вижу в Вашем тексте решения для поставленного вопроса. Стоит ли предпринимать какие-то действия или оставить как есть?

Comment: @alexolut Формулировка “Этот вопрос уже был задан и имеет решение…" не обманывает, если понимать, что она означает. Формулировку можно не менять, а объяснять и обучать как пользоваться - надо.

Comment: Точная текущая формулировка (в вопрос вставляется): *"this question  already has an answer here:<link>"*, что можно перевести: «вопрос уже имеет решение: <ссылка>». Рассматриваемая формулировка причины закрытия не совсем удачна: она делает акцент на поверхностную похожесть формулировок вопросов, в не на то, что их решения всегда идентичны (суть одинакова)—разница достаточно тонкая.

Comment: @jfs Если под "решением" понимается ответ с галочкой, то его наличие не требуется в вопросе при установке дубликата. Осуществите поиск с 'duplicate:yes' и убедитесь в этом сами. Gleb, Вы исходите из неверных предположений в своем ответе, Ваш ответ не соответствует действительности.

Comment: @alexolut даже ответ с галочкой не гарантирует, что решение найдено. Исходить надо из того, что участник, который нашёл дубликат, способен понять работает или нет решение. Если окажется что заметная доля вопросов-оригиналов не имеют адекватного решения, тогда можно подумать как участникам, которые находят дубликаты внушить, что вопрос-оригинал обязан уже иметь решение. [Близкая тема](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4003/23044)

Comment: @jfs именно поэтому слово "решение" вообще не стоит использовать в формулировке. answer - это не решение. Это ответ (с +1 хотя бы), если я не ошибаюсь.

Comment: @alexolut Нет решения—нет дубликата. Я не говорю про ограничения самой системы. Ничто не гарантирует что решение найдено (ни плюсы ни галочки—прочтите ссылку которую я дал). Ещё раз: есть ли или нет решения—на усмотрение участника, который закрывает вопрос как дубликат. Чтобы не заниматься обсуждением сферических коней в вакууме, необходимо сперва данные найти, что голосование сломано: что "заметная доля" дубликатов без решений (как я выше сказал).

Comment: @jfs "Нет решения—нет дубликата" - далеко не факт. Если есть несколько одинаковых по смыслу вопросов, то они дубликаты, несмотря на отсутствие по ним каких-либо ответов. Чтобы понять существует ли "заметная доля дубликатов без решений" нужно очень хорошо разбираться в предметной области каждого такого вопроса. Но из списка таких вопросов можно будет сразу выкинуть те, для которых ТС нажал кнопку "Это решило мою проблему". Такие вопросы с вероятностью 99% будут действительно являться дубликатами. Т.е. они практически не привносят доп.информации на сайт.

Comment: @alexolut: если вы не тролль, то я прошу вас указать какую реальную проблему вы хотите решить. Я ясно вижу достоинства для сайта принятой политики, что не следует закрывать вопрос как дубликат, если нет решения (что в частности выражается в языке интерфейса). Если вы думаете, что такая политика вредна и её следует изменить, то создайте отдельное обсуждение с обоснованием, почему вы думаете её следует изменить.

Comment: @jfs к чему тут вообще про тролля? Проблема поставлена автором вопроса. Моё решение - изменить перевод согласно реалиям механизма дубликатов (я даже ответом это оформил). Вопроса об изменении самого подхода к работе с дубликатами автором не ставилось. Ответ, под которым мы сейчас пишем комментарии вообще выходит за рамки исходного вопроса, особенно учитывая, что вопрос не содержит метки `обсуждение`.

Answer (score -1):

Оказалось, что в [оригинале](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40264408?key=a09b386a03fda6b8b4d90dee515b3e5a) это всего лишь `duplicate of...`

А вот [пояснение](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40264391?key=ca6db24ecd359c55a74650aaabcc03da):

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

переведено более точно:

> Вопрос уже задавался ранее, и на него уже есть ответ.

Поэтому, выбирая этот пункт в качестве причины закрытия, всё таки нужно иметь в виду, что ответ уже присутствует (не уверен, но возможно система даже не позволит выбрать вопрос, на который не поступило ещё ответов).

Предлагаю сделать такой вариант:

> дубликат существующего вопроса.

Пояснение оставить без изменений.

Comment: Система не даёт выбрать вопрос, в котором нет ответа, помеченного как решение. Проверял. Поэтому если на сайте повторяют вопрос, на который до сих пор нет удовлетворительного ответа, то его нельзя закрыть как дубликат. Что логично, имхо.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky вот мой удалённый вопрос http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4000, который был помечен как дубликат вопроса http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3651 в котором **нет ответа, помеченного как решение**.

Comment: @edem: мета-вопросы это совершенно отдельная категория--здесь и голосование и правила другие. Например, можно закрыть вопрос как дубликат без существующего ответа (на основном сайте так нельзя).

Comment: @jfs тем более не понимаю зачем белое называть чёрным. "Решение" и "Схожесть".

Comment: @edem Имхо система предлагает закрывать как дубликаты только те вопросы, решение для которых уже есть в другом вопросе. Но этой возможностью могут воспользоваться несправедливо. Это бывает и на русском, и на английском сайтах. Это человеческий фактор.

Comment: @edem под ответом понимается не сообщение с галочкой, а сообщение хотя бы с одним плюсом, если я не ошибаюсь. И я не уверен, что в этом правиле есть исключения для Мета сайта. На момент закрытия Вашего вопроса как дубликата, ответ с +1 уже имелся в другой (более старой) теме.