# Какую использовать тревогу для одинаковых вопросов, заданных одним и тем же человеком?

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги

Какую тревогу использовать в таком случае:

- [Подскажите редирект со всех страниц с цифрами в URL на такие же без цифр?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/915906/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86-%D1%81-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-url-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80)
- [Как сделать редирект со всех страниц с цифрами в ЧПУ на такие де без цифр?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/915756/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86-%D1%81-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%A7%D0%9F%D0%A3-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80)
- [Как через .htaccess сделать редирект со страниц с цифрами на такие же без цифр?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/915637/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-htaccess-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86-%D1%81-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80)

Три вопроса одинаковы и заданы одним и тем же человеком. Среди тревог нашёл только *"Вопрос уже задавался ранее, и на него уже есть ответ."* Но мне кажется, этот вариант не подходит, так как ответа  нет.

На данный момент отметил просто: *"требуется вмешательство модератора"*.

Comment: Чем "дубликат" не устраивает?

Comment: @cppquestions отсутствием ответа. ТС как раз об этом говорит.

Comment: @älёxölüt понял. Можно почитать [это](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5219/317064) тогда

Comment: "Штамповка идентичных вопросов" нет стандартной тревоги, случается не часто. Поэтому было правилным отметить:  "требуется вмешательство модератора".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

То, что ответа ещё нет — совершенно не проблема для закрытия как «дубликат» по причине «Данный вопрос уже был задан и имеет решение». Создавать несколько одинаковых вопросов с небольшими вариациями по формулировке не допускается. Если требуется какое-то уточнение, и ответа ещё никто не предоставил, надо вносить правку в исходный вопрос вместо публикации нового вопроса.

К тому же с формулировкой причины имеется проблема перевода с английского на русский, которая вносит дополнительный смысл, отсутствующий в оригинале. Можете сами [убедиться](https://ru.traducir.win/string/6886):

> This question is an exact duplicate of:

> Данный вопрос уже был задан и имеет решение:

Такая проблема перевода уже [обсуждалась ранее](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4001/176217), видимо, пора брать её решение в свои руки.

Answer (score 0):

Либо закрытие как дубликата, либо тревогу для модератора, либо обе.

Модератор может объединить разные вопросы в один - при этом перенесутся комментарии и ответы. Однако, для этого один из вопросов уже должен быть закрыт как дубликат (модератор может закрыть самостоятельно).

Если ни ответов, ни комментариев нет, то вполне можно просто задубликатить и, возможно, проголосовать за удаление.