# Что значит красный круг в очереди проверок?

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок

В очереди проверок "Сообщения низкого качества" сейчас пусто, однако в меню горит какой-то красный круг. Что это значит и значит ли это что-то вообще?

И еще: почему иногда он красный, иногда серый, иногда его нет?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: серый если есть хоть одна. красная если в очереди их больше кого-то количества. У вас красная потому что хоть вы все проверили, но в очереди все равно остались сообщения которую ждут проверки от других пользователей

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, оказывается, можно заявить в дубликаты вопрос без ответов. это, видимо, мета-фишка?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, без ответов везде можно. Нельзя только с ответом с нулевым рейтингом, вроде. Или какая-то подобная магия.

Comment: @Qwertiy, на основном сайте: можно без ответов, если у обоих вопросов один автор. если авторы разные, то ответ не только должен быть, но и у него должен быть баланс голосов выше нуля.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, проверь ещё раз с разными авторами без ответов. Насколько я помню, можно.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Это, разумеется, очень по теме вопроса :), однако чисто с точки зрения логики это... ЛОГИЧНО. Вряд ли отрицательные ответы как-то помогут.

Comment: @Qwertiy, проверил: «[Этот вопрос — без принятого ответа или без ответа, за который были отданы голоса](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKy15.png)». вот этот вопрос [без ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/708877/178576) я и попробовал заявить как дубликат при «закрытии» [вот этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1252511/178576). вопросы — первые попавшиеся под руку. // т.е., сымитировал ситуацию с данным вопросом, под которым мы флудом занимаемся.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin [известная история](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4001/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ad%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5#comment13173_4004)