# Нет переводов фраз об открытии доступа к очередям проверок "Голоса за закрытие" и "Голоса за переоткрытие"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

Заголовок сформулировать лучше я не смог. Легче показать:
[image: ruStackOverlow]
[image: ruStackOverflow Meta]

Как видим и на ruSO, и на ruSOMeta отображаются надписи: `Awarded at 3k reputation`. Предполагаю, что все 4 надписи используют один перевод.

Предложения перевода: `Присуждается за _ репутации`, `Открывается на _ репутации` или `Доступно при _ репутации`. Количество репутации, вроде указывается не числом, а через $, но это уже не ко мне.

Увидеть текст можно открыв [страницу очередей проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review) в приватном режиме браузера.

Comment: Есть такое понятие популярное на SE как FHRC (Free-Hand Red Circle). Это когда корявенько, но всё же обозначают на скриншоте места, на которые следует обратить внимание. Рекомендую взять на вооружение.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Выделять красным кружком? Почему меня преследуют [красные кружки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11404/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba)? Понял, принял в арсенал!

Comment: Аха-ха. Ну это всё же немного разные кружки. Ручные точно не нужно заливать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала оригинал не содержал слова "reputation" и перевод был выполнен ещё пару дней назад:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15703

Теперь слово добавилось и перевод предсказуемо слетел. Добавил по аналогии:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16197

Будет не сайте в новых сборках. Текущая  rev 2021.3.9.38752